# CSS text-positioning with "viewport-width" property

Tags: html, css

When I create a `div` with `h1` inside I set `margin-left` to `h1` 55vw(viewport-width). And it's ok with my 1378px-width monitor but when I decided to resize my browser `h1` text start to outdone/outstrip the image. How can I set it right in the position I need to in any size of the screen(except of very high/low resolution).

HTML code:

```
<div class="logo-container">
        <h1 class="text">
            Netherlands
        </h1>
    </div>
```

Its CSS:

```
<style>
    .logo-container {
        background: url(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo9w.png) no-repeat center;
        padding: 28px 0 14px;
    }
    .text {
        margin-top: 62px;
        margin-left: 55vw;
        font: 16px Arial;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I want the text to start underneath 'L' letter of "GOOGLE"

Comment: If you want the size of the h1 to scale with the window width, why don't you set the font-size in `vw` too?

Comment: your margin left needs to be a relative distance compared to the size of the text so use a value of `em` because you cab have a view port width but this is completely different from the actual text size displayed on the viewport (if you want the text to appear relative to other text on the page)

Comment: @Martin setting margin value to `em` doesn't help. The text just has freezed instead of moving with background-image.

Comment: hmmm, ok - that's a shame, but using `em` was my only idea for keeping the texts relative to each other (the Google and the Netherlands)

Comment: sorry I was thinking the Google was a text rather than an image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Try this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/91x4mfyf/)

The logo container is centered horizontally with auto margins. The text is positioned absolutely relative to the logo container. This way no matter where the logo ends up the text will absolutely be in the correct location.

HTML

```
<div class="logo-container">
    <h1 class="text">
        Netherlands
    </h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.logo-container {
    background: url(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo9w.png) no-repeat;
    height: 95px;
    width: 269px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 210px;
    font: 16px Arial;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Comment: `left:215px` looks neater, but otherwise that's a good Fiddle :)

Comment: @dcabines thank you for the answer. And another one question: if logo isn't centered but moved for some percents right or left does this issue help in this case?                 upd: already tested it. Works correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are either goign to need to set [css media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) breakpoints and create a responsive layout where you control where it sets on each size viewport or do somethign like center it that works no matter the size.

Comment: but I want it smoothly not jump from breakpoints to breakpoints.

Comment: Firstly, generally users do not resize their screen while using a site, so it is extremely unlikely that a user would see any jerkiness..
Secondly, you can assign as many breakpoints as you want...so however much you are willing to do is how jerky it would be...maybe using [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) to create the stylesheet rules would save you some time.

Comment: ok. then if no one suggests better solution I'll accept yours one. But still thinking about shorter way of it.

Comment: @dcabines's answer may be what you are actually looking for now that you have clarified your needs.

Comment: @DrCord I do occasionally resize my screen while visiting a website, usually by pressing F11.

Comment: I didn't say that people DO NOT resize their screens, I do it as well. I said that users GENERALLY do not resize their screens, meaning it is a fairly minor issue and potentially not worth worrying about if a few users see your text move when they resize the screen as most users will never see that happen.

Comment: @DrCord but I can't organize relations between image and h1 on screens that are much bigger than mine. Something like 3000+px width

Comment: @Vad Zelenin - Why are you telling me that? You should use dcabines answer, it should work for giant screens.

Answer (score 0):

Or try this:

```
    .logo-container {
        background: url(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo9w.png) no-repeat center;
        padding: 28px 0 14px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .text {
        margin-top: 15px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        font: 16px Arial;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;         
    }
```